# I can't figure out how to resolve Python Praw deprecation warning

Tags: python, praw

```
./update.py:63: DeprecationWarning: Positional arguments for 'WikiPage.edit' will no longer be supported in PRAW 8.
Call this function with 'content' as a keyword argument.
  reddit.subreddit(subreddit).wiki['config/sidebar'].edit(newsidebar)
```

I don't understand what it is telling me.

I tried..

`reddit.subreddit(subreddit).wiki['content'].edit(newsidebar)`

but it doesn't work and I still get the warning.

Comment: Its saying positional arguments will no longer be supported, so I guess you need `reddit.subreddit(subreddit).wiki['content'].edit(the_arg=newsidebar)` where `the_arg` is the name of the argument you're passing. But note this is a deprecation warning not an error - it means that your code should work today but might break later when you upgrade to PRAW 8 from whatever you have installed,

Comment: I literally just figured this out.  I was taking "positional arguments" as arguments that describe a position on the reddit page for some reason lol.

Comment: Yeah I can see how that would be confusing :)

Answer (score -1):

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore",category=DeprecationWarning)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Sweeping warnings under the rug isn't a solution. It just ensures your code will produce actual errors the next time you update that library.